# Vert'x with angular 2, add a valid static root

Tags: angular, vert.x

For our project, i need a static import for angular2 in vert'x web.

Here is my code :

```
router.route("/*").handler(StaticHandler.create());
```

Here is my tree:

> src/main/webroot/static/*

But, I've a Not Found error. 
I looked for a solution on stackoverflow, goal, I found nothing.
The possible duplicate don't resolve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertx Webroot In Fat Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782818/vertx-webroot-in-fat-jar)

Comment: Nope, i try this solution and don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this is because that your static files are not on the classpath. Do you bundle them in jar? or expose directly on classpath?

1. The `StaticHandler` will by default look for them under path `webroot`, so if you would like to serve them from within jar, they need to be bundled under `/webroot/...`.
2. If you want to serve them directly on the classpath then you can do so by for example `vertx run -cp ./src <your-verticle>`